# python wouldn't scrape the texts but gives me an empty white space

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape some customer reviews from Trip Advisor website.
For some of the reviews, I could scrape without any problem but for the others, I couldn't scrape properly. It just gives me an empty white space.
Could anyone help with this?
Below is my simplified code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re 

b_link="https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60607-d1468361-r460991443-Ohana_House_Volcano_s_Popular_Rainforest_Retreat-Volcano_Island_of_Hawaii_Hawaii.html"

links_open_b=urlopen(b_link)
soup_b=BeautifulSoup(links_open_b,"html.parser")
first_text_b=soup_b.find_all("div", class_="entry vrReviewText")
actual_text_b=first_text_b[0].text
actual_text_b=re.sub('\s+',' ',actual_text_b)
print (actual_text_b)
```

What I can get:

```
Just an empty white space.
```

What I want to get:
The Ohana house at Volcano was an absolutely perfect match for our family and our 5 day stay on the Big Island.
...
we had a great time in every aspect of our visit, and would highly recommend this house for anyone who wants to explore the eastern side of the Big Island.

Comment: Please add your imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The review is actually loaded via

```
https://www.tripadvisor.com/UserReviewController?a=fullTrans&r=460991443
```

To get the review, you can use the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module:

```
import requests

URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/UserReviewController?a=fullTrans&r=460991443"

response = requests.get(URL).json()

print(response[0]["body"])
```

Output:

```
The Ohana house at Volcano ... side of the Big Island.
```

Comment: Thank you. How did you get to that URL?

Comment: @Todd In your browser go to:  Developer tools -> Network